# Why doesnt vector support size as member variable like length variable in a Java class, instead a function size()?

Tags: java, c++, optimization, stl

Why doesn't `std::vector` or other containers have `length` as a member variable, instead of a function? Reading a vector's size using a function is more costly than a member variable.

```
vector<int> v;
....
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
....
}
```

In the above example, it should always call `size()` function, and it requires more CPU cycle. I think Java library uses more optimized approach in this than C++ STL in the design.

I understand it has a private member function and library designers likely wanted to restrict to access from outside of a class.

Any comment/idea?

Comment: Your claim that calling a getter function requires more CPU cycles is false with any compiler that isn't ancient. Inlining this is trivial nowadays. You can see this for yourself by looking at generated assembly and/or measuring.

Comment: How would you stop an application updating `size` and thereby corrupting the state of the vector?

Comment: `length` field is declared as `final` but in C++ the `final` keyword does not exist and its behaviour, as far as I know, cannot be emulated. Moreover, in C++ there is not the concept of `readonly` property(as in C# for example).

Comment: @RichardCritten I don't know much about Java programming. How does a Java class prevent length variable to be updated its outside? If it's updated, it will also cause to violate memory.

Comment: The nearest Java class to std::vector is ArrayList, size of an array list is a method call.  I think you need to check your assumption that Java uses a size property for mutable objects.

Comment: As a matter of fact the final keyword does exists and I can emulate a read-only property very easily but why bother when a plain function does the job at no cost ?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final

Comment: Also consider writing that loop as `for (int value: v)` and letting the compiler and runtime worry about how big  `v` is.

Comment: Why is my question voted down to -4? What is wrong in my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't std::vector or other containers have length as a member variable, instead of a function?

Because it would be writable if it was a public member variable.  Since it makes no sense to write to the size member of a vector, the designers made the size member private and provided a `size()` method to read its value.  A java array's `length` member is declared `final` so you can't change it.  You could do the same thing in C++ with a `const` length member, but `std::vector` needs to be able to change its `length`, so that doesn't make sense either.  That's the same reason java's `ArrayList` class uses a `size()` method rather than a public member (that and so that it can provide dynamic dispatch through the `List` interface).

> Reading a vector's size using a function is more costly than a member variable.

It really isn't.  The method's definition is available at the point of the call, so the call will almost certainly be inlined by any decent compiler.  In the end, the compiler will end up generating the exact same machine code for a public member variable or an accessor method.

Comment: I can define a nested class with a size member value which implicitely convert to the const reference of the size field. it would uselessly tie the implementation of std::vector to ptr+size field implementation.

Comment: That also has lots of downsides.  For instance, template type deduction and `auto` variables won't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't std::vector or other containers have length as a member
>   variable, instead of a function?

Because if length was member, it has 2 downsides:
(i) sizeof(vector) will be bigger because of this member.
(ii) any operations than change the vector: clear(), insert(), erase(), push_back(), pop_back(), emplace_back() swap() will have to adjust this member which would make these operations slower.

It is not necessarily slower either because if size() is implemented as  wrapper function returning member data, this will be inlined by a good compiler.

As it stands, vector is typically implemented as 3 pointers: a pointer to the start of a memory block, a pointer to just beyond the last valid element and a pointer to just beyond the end of the memory block. size() is then the difference between the last valid element and the start of the memory block (in terms of number of elements). It is similar to ptrdiff_t.

Member functions give freedom to the vendor to implement as they see best, making sure they comply with the ISO C++ standard.